# pass Attribute of a class as input parameter of a function of the class in cpp

Tags: c++, class, oop

Considering a class as

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass
{
   public:
     int x;
     int y;
     myClass(int _x, int _y): x{_x}, y{_y}{}
     void foo(int z) { std::cout << z;}
};

int main()
{
   myClass my_class(2,3);
   my_class.foo(my_class.x);
}
```

which means in object of a class,  a function of the class is called by passing attribute of the class. it compiles and works for the simple example. But would it make any problem?

Comment: No, there's no problem doing this but if `foo` is always supposed to use the same `x` as `this->x` then you could just skip the parameter and just use `x` inside `foo`

Comment: The point is that it is an example. if z would be x or y at runtime, what would happen?

Comment: If you change `foo(int z)` to `foo(int x)` nothing will happen other than that the `x` in the function will shadow the member variable `x`

Answer (score 1):

No there is no problem. `foo` takes its argument by value, it makes a copy. Maybe it helps to see it like this which is almost equivalent:

```
int main()
{
   myClass my_class(2,3);
   int a = my_class.x;
   my_class.foo(a);
}
```

Or view it like this, you are basically asking: Is it a problem to pass the value `2` to `foo`? No.

Comment: What if foo takes the parameter as reference, i.e. foo(int& z)?

Comment: @Pejvak still no problem. Why do you think it would be problematic? There seems to be some misunderstanding. I can help better if you tell me what it is

Comment: Thanks for your help. The point is that it is a simple example. I want to use the same strategy in a big code where z can get value of x or y chosen in runtime. I was wondering whether it makes any problem and/or is there any smarter way to do it.